# Determining Turn Order

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I wanted to try it like this, but I don't want to nest a bunch of for loops or if statements. For some reason I'm not seeing what the actual comparison should be to take the speeds list and populate turn order. Basically just comparing what each individual minion's speed is against the others using the sort function in it's own method and returning a list. Then I want to compare the list values against the key values stored in the minion_collection. I'm not sure if I'm setting myself up for a world of hurt here or not. Still somewhat new to python so I don't know many of the utilities.

```
minion_collection = {
    'minion1' : {
                    "name" : "zombie", "str" : 10, "def" : 5, "hp" : 25, "maxhp" : 25, "speed" : 15, "spdbar": 0},
    'minion2' : {
                    "name": 'cleric', "str": 4, "def": 5, "hp": 25,"maxhp": 25, "speed": 20, "spdbar": 0},
    'minion3' : {
                    "name" : "professor", "str" : 10, "def" : 5, "hp" : 25, "maxhp" : 25, "speed" : 15, "spdbar": 0},
    'minion4' : {
                    "name": 'hunter', "str": 4, "def": 5, "hp": 25,"maxhp": 25, "speed": 30, "spdbar": 0}
}

def initiative(speeds):
    for x in minion_collection:
        minion_collection[x]['spdbar'] = 100
    order = sort(speeds, reverse = True)
    return order
```

#### Where I start to determine the turn order

```
turn = 1
speeds = (fighter1['speed'], fighter2['speed'], pcfighter1['speed'], pcfighter2['speed'])
order = initiative(speeds)


for speed in order:
    if fighter1['speed'] == speed:
        first = fighter1
        second = '???'
        third = '???'
        last = '???'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `sorted()`

```
turn = 1
speeds = (fighter1['speed'], fighter2['speed'], pcfighter1['speed'], pcfighter2['speed'])
order = initiative(speeds)


for speed in sorted(order):
    if fighter1['speed'] == speed:
        first = fighter1
        second = '???'
        third = '???'
        last = '???'
```

Comment: Can I use the sorted() function and reference the speed key value in minion_collection? I don't want to sort the dictionary, I want to sort the fighters selected because there will definitely be duplicates selected.

Comment: @mstr_bgn ``sorted()`` doesn't modify the original list unless you explicitly declare ``lst = sorted(lst)``. Also sorry, I didn't understand your question. Do you want to sort the dictionary by a specific value?

Comment: The game I'm building is kind of a collector game. This is just a smaller version where there are dummy values in the collection. Eventually, the pc fighters will be static, and the user will select their fighters. I wanted to go by the speed of individual fighters to determine turn order, but I think for now I will just go by player turn, execute all actions by that player's fighters, and then pass the turn.

Comment: @mstr_bgn you can do something like this ```sorted(minion_collection, key=lambda minion: minion['speed'])``` but you'd have to turn that dictionary into a list abd instead, add a key "name" like this:
minion_collection = [{"name": "minion1", "speed": 23 ....}, {"name": "minion2"...}....]

EDIT: Just noticed yoy already have a "name" key. Just remove the "minion#: " and leave it as a list of dicts not a nested dictionary